# How to prevent next step to run in GitHub actions while a Kubernete pod is terminating and a new running pod is taking his place

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, automation, workflow, github-actions

After a Kubernetes deployment has been updated takes a moment to terminate the old pod and recreate a new one with a different ref-name, I wonder if there is any way to prevent the next step from running in GitHub actions before this terminating pod is being removed.

For a small window of time, we have two pods with different statuses referencing the same deployment which send an error if you try to run any command in your next GitHub action step.

[image]

I created a 30s delay in the previous step to give more time to remove the terminating pod but I am looking for a cleaner way to do it

e.g. "this is what I don't want to do in my GitHub action"

`- name: Sleep for 30 seconds`

`run: sleep 30s`

`shell: bash`

Thanks for you help...

Comment: Instead of sleep, perhaps loop in that step until you only see one deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.spec.strategy.type: Recreate` in the Deployment. This will force the previous pods to be terminated before creating new pod.

Here, is the official documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#strategy